# Retrieve and display the Url where a form has been completed in Laravel 5

Tags: php, html, laravel

I would like to add a feature to my messenger.

When a buyer sends a message to a seller from a listing, only from a listing ([www.website.com/listings/...](http://www.website.com/listings/...)) I would like to add a link to this listing in the messenger so that the seller can find the reference listing.

Here is the code (which does not work):

In message.blade.php (form):

`<input name="listingurl" type="hidden" value="<?php echo url()->current();?>">`

In MController.php:

`$listingurl = Input::get('listingurl');`

In show.blade.php (messenger):

`<a href="{{ $listingurl }}">Listing</a>`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think you should read about named routes. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#named-routes

Comment: do you pass the `$listingurl` variable to the view afterwards?

Comment: @user3532758 I'm new to laravel and I've already wasted a lot of time, that's why I'm asking for help here. If you know how to solve it, please let us know so we can share it with Stackoverflow users.

Comment: @IGP $listingurl is in show.blade.php (messenger page) as written, but it doesn't work. Do you have a recommandation ?

Comment: Named route is suggestion of code quality/readability or something of that sort. Extending on what IGP asked, can you share the relevant controller method? Or share how you pass `$listingurl` from the controller to `show` view.

Comment: First thing you should do is to do a `dd($request)` in the controller to check if you're getting the value of `listingurl`. If it does, make sure you have included the the `$listingurl` variable in your compact like this `return view ('show', compact('listingurl'));`.

Comment: @user3532758 Here is the controller file <https://www.codepile.net/pile/WqVXRo39> and show file <https://www.codepile.net/pile/V0qZY262>

Note: I didn't write the code, just purchase it on envato.

Comment: @fufubrocat can you take a look to the files ? https://www.codepile.net/pile/WqVXRo39 and https://www.codepile.net/pile/V0qZY262

I must have made a beginner's mistake (I am)

Note: I didn't write the code, just purchase it on envato.

Comment: Notice how you do not pass the `$listingUrl` to anything. It's just `$listingurl = Input::get('listingurl');` in the store method. And store method returns a redirect. So, my bet is that, IF you do not want to modify the db table, your best option would be to append the `$listingUrl` in the message body `'body' => $input['message']. "<br>".$listingUrl`. Otherwise, modify the messages table to include a column to store the `listingUrl`.

Comment: @user3532758 here is what I get https://prnt.sc/30XDb6X2mXS6 . How display the url as link (i.e Listing) ? It's possible to add a condition, because all messages don't come from a listing page ?

Comment: I tried:
`$target = Input::get('listingurl');
 $listingUrl = link($target, "test");`

and get **link(): No such file or directory**

Answer (score 0):

follow this options from laravel api to see what you want

https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.html#method_previous

here an example to Get the URL for the previous request without to use hidden input .

`$listingurl = url()->previous();`

and you can use it in your code for easy way
i don't understand what do you want but this may help you

`<a href="{{ $listingurl }}">Listing</a>`

i wish this solution saved your day

Comment: Thanks, but I already did it and it doesn't work. The value should be fixed and attached to each message written from an listing page.

Popup form: https://prnt.sc/YsfMyzqmR9gM
Messenger page: https://prnt.sc/-MmW24eTzEn9

Comment: Well I thought you wanted to attach a link that has no dynamic values
So you have to enter the main link and then attach the variable value to it
Can you give me the link you want to save?

Comment: Yes, I use an input value and <?php echo url()->current();?> to obtain the current url where the form is submitted

Comment: How to replace `$listingurl => url()->previous()` by an hyperlink named "Listing" ?

Comment: you can use url() function url('Listing') just that

Comment: I got the previous url but not as href. How to od that ?